# regular expression to replace with ','

Tags: javascript, regex

I have one RegExp, could anyone explain exactly what it does?

**Regexp**

```
b=b.replace(/(\d{1,3}(?=(?:\d\d\d)+(?!\d)))/g,"$1 ")
```

I think it is replacing with space(' ')

if i'm right, i want to replace it with comma(,) instead of space(' ').

Comment: Why is this tagged jQuery?

Comment: Try `b=b.replace(/(\d{1,3}(?=(?:\d\d\d)+(?!\d)))/g,"$1,") `

Comment: actually this regexp to convert a string from "1000" to "1 000", but i want like "1,000"

Comment: look what @ArunPJohny wrote :D

Answer (score 1):

To explain the regex, let's break it down:

```
(          # Match and capture in group number 1:
 \d{1,3}   # one to three digits (as many as possible),
 (?=       # but only if it's possible to match the following afterwards:
  (?:      # A (non-capturing) group containing
   \d\d\d  # exactly three digits
  )+       # once or more (so, three/six/nine/twelve/... digits)
  (?!\d)   # but only if there are no further digits ahead.
 )         # End of (?=...) lookahead assertion
)          # End of capturing group
```

Actually, the outer parentheses are unnecessary if you use `$&` instead of `$1` for the replacement string (`$&` contains the entire match).

Answer (score 0):

The regex `(\d{1,3}(?=(?:\d\d\d)+(?!\d)))` matches any 1-3 digits (`(\d{1,3}`) that is followed by a multiple of 3 digits (`(?:\d\d\d)+`), that isn't followed by another digit (`(?!\d)`). It replaces it with `"$1 "`. `$1` is replaced by the first capture group. The space behind it is... a space.

See [regexpressions on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for more information about the different syntaxes.

If you want to seperate the numbers with a comma, instead of a space, you'll need to replace it with `"$1,"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't try to solve everything by using regular expressions.**

Regular expressions are meant for *matching*, not to fix non-text-encoded-as-text formatting.

If you want to format numbers differently, extract them and use format strings to reformat them on a character processing level. That is just an *ugly hack*.

It is okay to use regular expressions to find the numbers in the text, e.g. `\d{4,}` but trying to do the actual formatting with regexp is a crazy abuse.